# How to write test cases for complex underlying entity?

Tags: java, junit4

I am wriring unit test cases for an existing system. The architecture for the underlying classes if very complex in itself.

> Blockquote
>   RequestHanndler ==> processes ==> Order ===> is dependent on ==> service layer == connected to ==> DB layer.

I am writing a test case for `RequestHandler`. The method in test(`doProcess()`) creates a new instance of `Order` class. `Order` class itself has very tight dependency on the service layer. I want to create an atomic test case, so, not any other layer of code will be executed.

What should the best process to create test cases for these scenrios?

Comment: "Order class itself has very tight dependency on the service layer." - why?

Comment: @Bedwyr It is not my design. This is like that, and I dont have any control over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might get a bit complicated when you want to write unit-tests for tighly coupled code. To make uni-testing easier you should better rely on abstractions and not on real implementations. E.g. the `Order` class shouldn't depend on the real implementation of the service layer, instead introduce an interface which is much easier to mock instead of a class which might be set to `final`.

Since your RequestHandler is responsible for creating the Order instances you'll have to provide a way to mock out the order class in unit-tests. A simply way is to create a protected method that simply creates a new order instance.

```
protected Order createOrder(String someParam) {
  return new Order(someParam);
}
```

In your Unit-Tests you can now extend the class and overwrite the factory-method.
Using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) this would look like:

```
protected Order createOrder(String someParam) {
  Order order = Mockito.mock(Order.class); // create mock object
  // configure mock to return someParam when 
  //  String Order#getSomeParam() gets invoked
  Mockito.doReturn(someParam).when(order).getSomeParam(); 
  return order;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical approach for unit testing of such systems is mocking. There are several mockup frameworks for java. I personally used EasyMock but there are others.

So, I think that you should to try to test the logic of request handler first. You should mock Order (i.e. create dummy, not real instance of order using mockup frameork). When this layer is tested go deeper and start testing internal layers.

Other strategy is going from down to up, i.e. test first the internal layers. This strategy is probably "right" but it you will not get fast results that you can show to your manager because managers typically like to see the "big" picture and very seldom go into the details.

Bottom line: good luck.

Comment: I thought of creating a mocked version of the Order class, But I am not able to identify any way to let RequestHandler to use the MockedOrder. Please suggest.